# How to specify insertion order for rows in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql

How can I specify the order in which rows are inserted into a SQL database?

e.g. I would like to insert my records by date in descending order.

```
cmd.CommandText = "select parkname,packname,duration,bookday from book where userid='"
    + Label15.Text + "' ORDER BY bookday DESC ";
rst = cmd.ExecuteReader();
rst.Read();
```

Comment: Insert statements can't have an order by clause.  Sorry.  That's why you're getting an error when attempting to do it.  The rest, is as RedFilter states.

Comment: i know dark. But my syntax for data retrieve in A descending order not work

Comment: A SQL (Server?) table does **not** have any specific order - you only get an order when you specifically ask for it when running a `SELECT`. Therefore, you **cannot** insert data in a specific order, either - you just insert the data - period. If you want it back in order of your date (descending), you need to say so in your `SELECT` by specifying `ORDER BY (datefield) DESC`

Answer (score 13):

Don't worry about the order you insert records.

The reason is, when selecting data back using SQL, the order in which the records are returned is undetermined unless you use an `ORDER BY` clause. If you want to maintain table order for performance reasons, use a clustered index on the column you want to order by.

If you just wish to select the data in descending order by date, do something like the following:

```
select MyColumn1, MyColumn2, MyDateColumn
from MyTable
order by MyDateColumn desc
```

Comment: thanks for help Filter. Actually ii want to retrieve records from database in  descending order of date.

Comment: Yes same syntax i am using to show other columns value according to date column value. But it not show correct data. so what can i do.

Comment: If the rows are not returning in the correct order, then the column you are sorting by may not be a datetime data type.

Comment: No its of datetime data type.

Comment: Please post sample data and your query. The schema DDL would be helpful as well.

Comment: If i am trying to enter record in descending order . it genrate error.

Comment: i have table named Book to which i want some column values.Query that i am using is as follows:

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "select parkname,packname,duration,bookday from book where userid='" + Label15.Text + "' ORDER BY bookday DESC ";
        rst = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        rst.Read();

Comment: That should work.  Add your table schema above, along with what the results are when you run this query.  That will give us enough to solve your problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

One of the features of a normalized relational database is that you do not need to worry about the order.  Each row stands on its own.  If you switch around 2 rows, the data is still the same and has the same meaning.

What you need is a datetime stamp.  Add a field to your table that stores a datetime, then set that field's default to GETDATE().  Then whenever you do an insert, that row will be datetime stamped.  Then you can use Order by in a query to present the data in the proper order.

Comment: can you tell me how to insert data in an descending order with respect to date

Comment: Yes: DON'T!  Its not something to try when using a relational database!